# After updating Android studio to Arctic Fox version and upgrade gradle to 7.0.0 I get gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating Android studio to Arctic Fox version and upgrade Gradle to 7.0.0 I get Gradle error:
would you help me please to solve this problem?
I am using :

- ViewModel and LiveData
- Kotlin
- coroutines
- Hilt
- Room
- Work manager
- Opencsv

  ```
    Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
        at ...        Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_81ndl2arupw8e1yms1mvvhjf2.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_81ndl2arupw8e1yms1mvvhjf2$_run_closure1) values: [build_81ndl2arupw8e1yms1mvvhjf2$_run_closure1@357f1275]
        at build_81ndl2arupw8e1yms1mvvhjf2.run(F:\Projects\InfoContest\app\build.gradle:8)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 140 more
  ```

android in build.gradle :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mohalim.contest.alarm"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true


    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
androidResources {
    noCompress 'csv'
}
```

}

Comment: try with AGP version `7.1.0-alpha05`

Comment: @BurhanKhanzada same problem, thank you.

Comment: It works now after updating to 7.1.0-alpha05 and remove 
androidResources {
        noCompress 'csv'
}

Comment: I am also facing the same error. Any good advice?

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation after upgrading to
Gradle and AGP versions 7.
In my case, removing the block

```
javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }
```

from inside the android block, solved the problem.

Comment: Where did you put the code, just near block `android{ ... }`?

Comment: @NickUnuchek I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this block

```
androidResources {
    noCompress 'csv'
}
```

or replace it with

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'csv'
}
```