# Android Studio Arctic Fox build failed after update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

Android Studio updated to the newest *Arctic Fox* version, after opening a project it prompted me to update the Gradle plug-in, which I did.

Now everytime I try to run an app (with the updated plug-in) the build fails with the next output: `Zip file '/home/user/path-to-my-project/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk' already contains entry 'AndroidManifest.xml', cannot overwrite`

Old apps that are not updated to newest plug-in release does not have this problem.

I already tried with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583399/after-updating-android-studio-to-arctic-fox-version-and-upgrade-gradle-to-7-0-0) but it didn't help.

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.user.oauthpractice"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: how about remove that app-debug.apk file?

Comment: @AIMINPAN already tried it, but it creates it again and the problem persists.

Comment: Please add your app level build.gradle file. We can only assume what's going on in your build configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried clean project? including manual removing of every `build` dir?

Comment: @Jay sure, updated the question with the build.gradle file.

Comment: @RafaelMorgado you find any solution?

Comment: @Rajpal I just tried a third time to create a new project and it ran without any problems, I’m not sure what was the problem with the other two projects.

Comment: has anybody found a solution to this? the accepted answer does not apply to my project since I don't have that dependency.

Comment: @AwaisMajeed try creating a new project as I mentioned above, then just copy chunks of code from the original project to the new one.

Comment: @RafaelMorgado the issue was with one the modules that I had added, if I comment that out. It builds just fine. But I'll try your suggestion and create a new project.

Comment: @RafaelMorgado creating a new project did not help. I've found the issue though. This error only appears when I upgrade the gradle version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your build.gradle, after removing `implementation 'com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3'`, this problem is gone. No idea what went wrong underneath. You can simply upgrade the version to 1.1.1 to get rid of this problem.

Comment: has anybody found out the cause of this error? this solution is not generic. I do not have this dependency in project but I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Android Gradle Plugin from version 3.4.2 to 7.0.0 (and Gradle from 6 to 7) I also stared having the same error. In my case it turned out that `AndroidManifest.xml` was inside the directory that was pointed to by `resources.srcDir`. Gradle tried to copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` from that directory into APK where a compiled version was already bundled.

Comment: Do you have solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I upgraded the gradle plugin from 3.6 to 7.1.1) I had a library-project included (the old vending-licensing) and it helped to exclude the manifest like this (inside `android{}`):

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```